# Find the sum of the series $\frac{3}{1!+2!+3!}+\frac{4}{2!+3!+4!}+...$upto n terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the series $\frac{3}{1!+2!+3!}+\frac{4}{2!+3!+4!}+...$upto n terms.

Based on my experience I presumed it is a telescopic function but not able to convert it into telescopic function.

Comment: The nth term is $\frac{n+2}{n!+(n+1)!+(n+2)!}$

Comment: For $n = 1, 2, 3$ you get $\frac 26$, $\frac{11}{24}$ and $\frac{59}{120}$. This should allow you to guess a pattern. Which can then be proven, for instance, by induction.

Comment: I get the sum of infinite series as $1/2$ analytically, this series converges fast to this value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k+2}{k!+(k+1)!+(k+2)!}$.

$$
\begin{align*}
S_n & =\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k+2}{k!+(k+1)!+(k+2)!} \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k+2}{k![1+(k+1)+(k+1)(k+2)]} \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k+2}{k![(k+2)+(k+1)(k+2)]} \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k+2}{k!(k+2)^2} \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!} \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(k+2)-1}{(k+2)!} \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\frac{1}{(k+1)!}-\frac{1}{(k+2)!}\right] \\
& =\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{(n+2)!} \\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thankyou for your prompt reply, I knew that it could be solved by telescopic function but was not able to make it